# Autovacuum does not autovacuum often enough

Tags: postgresql

The vacuum does not execute regularly enough on some tables, therefore bloat is present on large tables.
To overcome this problem, I am setting up a weekly job that runs a vacuum analyze command.
Is this approach correct and is it compatible with good practice?

Comment: Best practice is to make sure that that is actually the problem first.  If you have something holding a snapshot open, you can vacuum all day long and never make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly correct, but a better practice is to tune autovacuum.

On the table wher you want autovacuum to work as fast as a manual `VACUUM`, reduce the cost delay to 0:

```
ALTER TABLE busytab SET (autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0);
```

This will work, except if the problem is that you have strong locks on the table often enough to interrupt autovacuum (manual `VACUUM` won't be interrupted, but would block those locks). If you take such locks often, you are probably doing something wrong with the database and should find a better solution.

The best practice here is never to use the `LOCK` statement.

Comment: Ok thanks. If we do not want to deal with the problem table by table, modifying autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit to 2000 for example to make the autovacuum more aggressive can also be appropriate?

Comment: Yes. But typically, not all your tables are very busy.